# Canary deployment to AWS lambda routing users not traffic

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, canary-deployment

I am working with AWS lambda and I am using lambda aliases to shift traffic gradually during deployments.
I know that AWS lambda alias is routing traffic with a simple probabilistic model to distribute the traffic between the two function versions.

I want to route the users not traffic, how can this be done?

I tried working with lambda versions, and AWS code deploy without success